# Screenshot isn't attached to allure results folder and in the allure report

Tags: java, selenium, testng, allure

Screenshot isn't attached to allure results folder and in the allure report. I don't understand what's the problem. Have tried to add listeners in testng.xml and in the test class above the test name - no difference-> the png file isn't shown in the allure results when the test is failed. What am I doing wrong?

```
public class AllureReportListener implements ITestListener {
   @Attachment(value = "Page screenshot", type = "image/png")
    public byte[] saveScreenshotPNG (WebDriver driver) {
        return ((TakesScreenshot) driver).getScreenshotAs(OutputType.BYTES);
    }
    @Override
    public void onStart(ITestContext iTestContext) {
        System.out.println("Starting Test Suite '" + iTestContext.getName() + "'.......");
        iTestContext.setAttribute("WebDriver", BaseTest.getDriver());
    }

    @Override
    public void onFinish(ITestContext iTestContext) {
        System.out.println("Finished Test Suite '" + iTestContext.getName() + "'");
    }

    @Override
    public void onTestStart(ITestResult iTestResult) {
        System.out.println("Starting Test Method '" + getTestMethodName(iTestResult) + "'");
    }

    @Override
    public void onTestSuccess(ITestResult iTestResult) {
        System.out.println("Test Method '" + getTestMethodName(iTestResult) + "' is Passed");
    }

    @Override
    public void onTestFailure(ITestResult iTestResult) {
        System.out.println("Test Method '" + getTestMethodName(iTestResult) + "' is Failed");
        if (BaseTest.getDriver() != null) {
            System.out.println("Screenshot has captured for the Test Method '" + getTestMethodName(iTestResult) + "'");
            saveScreenshotPNG(BaseTest.getDriver());
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onTestSkipped(ITestResult iTestResult) {
        System.out.println("Test Method '" + getTestMethodName(iTestResult) + "' is Skipped");
    }

    @Override
    public void onTestFailedButWithinSuccessPercentage(ITestResult iTestResult) {
    }

    private static String getTestMethodName(ITestResult iTestResult) {
        return iTestResult.getMethod().getConstructorOrMethod().getName();
    }
}
```

Comment: What version of Allure are you using? Can you try calling screenshot method directly to see if the PNG is generated without being part of onTestFailure.

Comment: I try to guess. Are you using cucumber BDD in the project?

Answer (score 0):

Try to add file extension argument for @Attachment annotation

```
    @Attachment(value = "Page screenshot", type = "image/png", fileExtension = ".png")
public byte[] saveScreenshotPNG (WebDriver driver) {
        return ((TakesScreenshot) driver).getScreenshotAs(OutputType.BYTES);
    }
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).